# Debian 10 /etc/modprobe.d/sound.conf Settings

Tags: debian, audio, intel

```
Audio: Device-1: Intel Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series 
Audio Cluster 
vendor: Realtek
driver: snd_hda_intel
v: kernel
bus ID: 00:0e.0
chip ID: 8086:5a98 
Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.10.0-5mx-amd64
```

I was getting Dummy Output from Volume Control, until I changed `/etc/modprobe.d/sound.conf` to read:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=generic
```

Then, after rebooting, "HDMI / Display port" was selected in the "Output Devices" tab (it looks like I have all the drivers). There were no other options available. See images.

I suspect `model=` is the culprit. What should actually go here?

Also, here is the Driver info from Windows. Perhaps an NDISWrapper solution can be organized.

```
ESAuDriver Device
C:\Windows\system32\DRIVERS\ESAuDriver.sys
C:\Windows\system32\drivers\ksthunk.sys
Provider: Everest Semiconductor Co., Ltd
File version: 1.0.0.1
Copyright: (C) 2018
Digital Signer: Microsoft Corporation Hardware Compatibility

FxSound Audio Enhancer
C:\Windows\system32\DRIVERS\dmk.sys
C:\Winodws\system32\drivers\fxvad.sys
C:\Windows\system32\drivers\ksthunk.sys
C:\Windows\system32\DRIVERS\portcls.sys
Provider: Microsoft Corporation
File version: 10.0.19041.746 (WinBuild.160101.0800)
Copyright: (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved
Digital Signer: Microsoft Windows

Intel(R) Display Audio
C:\Windows\system32\DRIVERS\dmk.sys
C:\Windows\system32\drivers\ksthunk.sys
C:\Windows\system32\DRIVERS\portcls.sys
C:\Windows\system32\SysFXVI.dll
C:\Windows\system32\WMALFXGFXDSP.dll
intcdaud.inf_amd64_5282259550ac75e5\IntcDAud.sys
Provider: Microsoft Corporation
File version: 10.0.19041.746 (WinBuild.160101.0800)
Copyright: (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
Digital Signer: Microsoft Windows

Intel(R) Smart Sound Technology (Intel(R) SST)
C:\Windows\system32\DRIVERS\dmk.sys
C:\Windows\system32\DRIVERS\IntcSST.sys
C:\Windows\system32\drivers\ksthunk.sys
C:\Windows\system32\DRIVERS\portcls.sys
Provider: Microsoft Corporation
File version: 10.0.19041.746 (WinBuild.160101.0800)
Copyright: (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
Digital Signer: Microsoft Windows
```

[image: Volume Control Output Devices Tab]

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to know that a "Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900" is a bit of a special case. It needs some options set in the "ALSA for SoC audio support" section of the kernel configuration. You'll need to know that these processors are known as the "Apollo Lake" platform.

I have a mini-ITX board with a Celeron N3150 (an earlier model but a similar special case), but it is currently out of commission because its NIC failed. So I'll have to rely on my notes here...

For my system, I absolutely had to select:

- ALSA for SoC audio support (`CONFIG_SND_SOC=m`)
- Intel ASoC SST drivers (`CONFIG_SND_SOC_INTEL_SST_TOPLEVEL=y`)
- and the appropriate platform option, which in your case would be "Broxton/ApolloLake platforms" (`CONFIG_SND_SOC_INTEL_APL=m`)

You may also wish to select:

- Sound Open Firmware support (`CONFIG_SND_SOC_SOF_TOPLEVEL=y`)
- SOF support for Intel Audio DSPs (`CONFIG_SND_SOC_SOF_INTEL_TOPLEVEL=y`)
- SOF PCI enumeration support (`CONFIG_SND_SOC_SOF_PCI=m`)
- SOF support for Apollolake (`CONFIG_SND_SOC_SOF_APOLLOLAKE_SUPPORT=m`)
- SOF support for HDA Links (HDA/HDMI) (`CONFIG_SND_SOC_SOF_HDA_LINK=y`)
- SOF support for HDAudio codecs (`CONFIG_SND_SOC_SOF_HDA_AUDIO_CODEC=y`)

These options will allow you to use Sound Open Firmware, if you later find out you'll need (or want) it.

Even if you are not familiar with building custom kernels, you should check your kernel configuration (typically available as a `/boot/config-*` file matching your kernel version number, or possibly as `/proc/config.gz`).

Start with `grep SND_SOC_INTEL_APL /boot/config-*` or `zcat /proc/config.gz | grep SND_SOC_INTEL_APL` if you have `/proc/config.gz`.

If the result you get is either

```
CONFIG_SND_SOC_INTEL_APL=m
```

or

```
CONFIG_SND_SOC_INTEL_APL=y
```

then the most essential part of the kernel sound configuration should be OK for your hardware. But if you get:

```
# CONFIG_SND_SOC_INTEL_APL is not set
```

or nothing at all, then the sound issue is probably caused by your kernel configuration, and you will need to either find a kernel package that has the appropriate options set, or build a kernel with a custom configuration for your system.

Note: Debian 11 was recently released. It uses kernel version 5.10 as standard, and its kernel configuration for amd64 hardware has `CONFIG_SND_SOC_INTEL_APL=m` enabled by default. If you are not absolutely required to stay with Debian 10, you might want to consider upgrading to Debian 11.

Debian has a pretty long history of managing major release upgrades without reinstalling, but you should [read the release notes](https://www.debian.org/releases/bullseye/amd64/release-notes/) first. Pay special attention to the Chapters 4 and 5, or the upgrade procedure and things you need to be aware of in Debian 11, respectively.

Comment: root@xxxxx:/home/xxxxxx# grep SND_SOC_INTEL_APL '/boot/config-5.10.0-5mx-amd64'
CONFIG_SND_SOC_INTEL_APL=m

Comment: Well  CONFIG_SND_SOC_INTEL_APL=m  is already set.  What to do now? I'm an experienced 'nix user; however, this is a lot of drilling down.